# How to use a LocalDate as the column of a TreeTableView / TableView

Tags: java, javafx, binding, callback, localdate

New to JavaFX, I have just learned how to set a cell value factory using a Callback: in Groovy this is like this:

```
fxmlController.treeTableView.columns.get( 0 ).cellValueFactory =
        new Callback<TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures, ObservableValue>() {
            @Override
            Binding call(TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures cellDataFeatures ) {
                // NB it turns out that the first "value" is a TreeItem
                Task task  = cellDataFeatures.value.value
                Bindings.createStringBinding( { task.title } )
            }
        }
```

... but what do I do if my next column is a column of `LocateDate` / `LocateDateTime` values? There is no static method `Bindings.createLocalDateTimeBinding()`...

For the record, I think I need a bidirectional binding, in the sense that I want this to display but I also want the user to be able to edit.

But maybe this has nothing to do with this: I'm thinking of the rather complicated arrangements for editing `JTree` items in Swing: editor component, all that kind of thing. I have no idea yet how this works in JavaFX.

**Edit**

James_D gave me some valuable clues, enough to display these values in the cell. Editing is proving a bit trickier. My first attempt was this:

```
dueDateCol.cellFactory = TextFieldTableCell.<Task>forTableColumn()
```

This gives an exception and giant stack trace on `Stage.show()`:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread"
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.time.LocalDate cannot be cast 
to class java.lang.String (java.time.LocalDate and java.lang.String are
in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

I then thought that maybe I should try the "old school" method of configuring a cell editor: I followed the instructions [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm#CJAGAAEE), under "Alternative solution of cell editing".

Again this fails to launch (see stack trace below).

It is clear that for a non-string value to be represented in a cell it must be converted to `String`... At the moment I'm trying to identify exactly where this class cast exception is taking place. It is probably in the internals of `TableCell`. I also note that this occurs before the editor is actually called into service: i.e. instead at "show" time. Hmmmm...

More gory details:
Despite the fact that I am catching all `Throwable`s thrown inside `start()` and not printing to console, some internal something is still printing stack traces to the Terminal on `show()`. This is the start of it:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread"
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.time.LocalDate cannot be cast
    to class java.lang.String (java.time.LocalDate and java.lang.String
    are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')  
at core.EditingCell.updateItem(main.groovy)     
at javafx.scene.control.TableCell.updateItem(TableCell.java:665)    
at javafx.scene.control.TableCell.indexChanged(TableCell.java:469)  
at javafx.scene.control.IndexedCell.updateIndex(IndexedCell.java:120)
```

... in fact a log message which I have placed at the start of `core.EditingCell.updateItem()` (my `TableCell` extension class) does NOT get printed... I also note that there is no line number stipulated in the file main.groovy in the above.

Comment: https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.base/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#createObjectBinding(java.util.concurrent.Callable,javafx.beans.Observable...)

Comment: Regarding your later point,  your `Task` class should expose an `ObjectProperty<LocalDate>`, which you should return directly from the callback, instead of creating a new binding. The `Person` class in the [`TableView` Javadocs](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html) shows how to properly define a model object for use in JavaFX.

Comment: Thanks ... any chance that you might give me another hint about what to do when I want to edit in-cell a `LocalDate` displayed in a table like this? Updating my question...

Comment: Again, see the [docs](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/cell/TextFieldTableCell.html#%3Cinit%3E()): "Without a StringConverter specified, this cell will not be able to accept input from the TextField (as it will not know how to convert this back to the domain object)."

Comment: Thanks again. Will add my own answer to help others unless you care to add your own.